# Complex expressions don't execute in Alfresco activiti web version

Tags: alfresco, business-process-management

An expression with conditions does not work when testing a bpm process created in bpm-explorer alfresco activiti.

```
${document.attributes['EPR/DMS/DMBTR'] < 10000000
&& document.attributes['EPR/DMS/DMBTR'] >= 5000000
&& document.attributes['EPR/DMS/CONCERN_FLG'] == true} 
|| ${document.attributes['EPR/DMS/DMBTR'] >= 10000000}
```

such options do not work either

```
${(document.attributes['EPR/DMS/DMBTR'] < 10000000
&& document.attributes['EPR/DMS/DMBTR'] >= 5000000
&& document.attributes['EPR/DMS/CONCERN_FLG'] == true) 
|| document.attributes['EPR/DMS/DMBTR'] >= 10000000}
```

Displays error

```
Error parsing '${document.attributes['EPR/DMS/DMBTR'] < 10000000 \n&& \n(document.attributes['EPR/DMS/DMBTR'] > 5000000 || document.attributes['EPR/DMS/DMBTR'] = 5000000) \n&& document.attributes['EPR/DMS/CONCERN_FLG'] == true} \n|| ${document.attributes['EPR/DMS/DMBTR'] > 10000000 || document.attributes['EPR/DMS/DMBTR'] =10000000}': lexical error at position 143, encountered invalid character '=', expected expression token
```

Comment: Why don't you try replacing the ">=" operator with two operators yourself, writing them correctly in the process?

Comment: It doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Try using `&gt;` and `&lt;` instead of the `>` and `<`. This will encode the string correctly and hope it will help solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
execution.setVariable('EPR_DMS_DMBTR', document.attributes['EPR/DMS/DMBTR'])
execution.setVariable('EPR_DMS_CONCERN_FLG', document.attributes['EPR/DMS/CONCERN_FLG'])


${EPR_DMS_DMBTR < 10000000
&& EPR_DMS_CONCERN_FLG >= 5000000
&& EPR_DMS_DMBTR == true)
|| EPR_DMS_DMBTR >= 10000000}
```